# AWS Amplify GraphQL Query For Null Connections

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have the following in my schema for my AWS Amplify project:

```js
type DriveTime @model
@auth( rules: [
  {allow: groups, groups: ["Admin", "Instructor"]},
  { allow: private, provider: iam }
]) {
  id: ID!
  start: AWSDateTime!
  end: AWSDateTime!
  openRegistration: AWSDateTime!
  closeRegistration: AWSDateTime!
  vehicle: Vehicle @connection(name: "VehicleDriveConnection")
  instructor: Instructor @connection(name: "InstructorDriveConnection") @aws_cognito_user_pools @aws_iam
  student: Student @connection(name: "StudentDriveConnection")
  evaluation: DriveEvaluation @connection(name: "DriveEvaluationConnection")
}
```

I want to be able to list all drive times where the student connection is empty or null. I am able to get all driveTimes for a single student but not all driveTimes where there is no student.

Since I dont want students to be able to access drive times that are either not open for registration or already registered to another student I have added this to my schema:

```js
type AvailableDriveTime {
  id: ID!
  start: AWSDateTime!
  end: AWSDateTime!
  openRegistration: AWSDateTime!
  closeRegistration: AWSDateTime!
  instructorFirstName: String!
  instructorLastName: String!
}

type Query {
  listAvailableDriveTimes(limit: Int, nextToken: String): AvailableDriveTimesConnection @function(name: "listAvailableDriveTimes-${env}") @aws_cognito_user_pools @aws_iam
}
```

And this is my current query in the Lambda resolver:

```js
let currentDate = new Date();
const listDrives = `query ListDrives($limit: Int, $nextToken: String) {
  listDriveTimes(limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken, filter: {and: {openRegistration: {le: "${currentDate.toISOString()}"}, closeRegistration: {ge: "${currentDate.toISOString()}"}}}) {
    items {
      id
      start
      end
      openRegistration
      closeRegistration
      instructor {
        firstName
        lastName
      }
      student {
        username
      }
    }
    nextToken
  }
}`
```

My current solution is sorting in the lambda resolver then returning the right data but it seems like there has to be a more efficient way.